# Same function with different parameters

Tags: c++

I need to write a sum function which adds the parameters. The problem is I need to write one function but I need to call with different parameters. Here is an example.

**sum(2,5) --> 7**

**sum(3,5,10) -> 18**

Is there a way to this with one function?

Comment: Variadic arguments

Answer (score -4, accepted):

YES! With C++11, you can make a variadic function. Here is the code.

```
int sum(int n, ...){

   va_list list;
   va_start(list ,n);

   int x;

   int s=0;

   for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
       x = va_arg(list,int);
       s+=x;
   }

 return s;
}
```

In main, you can call `sum(2, 2, 5)`.

The first parameter is the number of parameter you have.

Also, you can call `sum(3, 3, 5, 10)` which will return 18.

Comment: While one can argue all day about the “VA” arguments/macros, variadic templates solve a different problem, IMOHO - and add a whole mess to the TU.

Comment: This code is the PRE-C++11 way to handle this issue. The C++11 way is to use a [**variadic template**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) instead. And in C++17, a [**fold expression**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) can be used to optimize the implementation further.

Comment: This will work but you can call it with just about anything and you can outright lie for interesting unchecked errors at runtime. For example, int x = sum(4400000000, "green eggs and ham", 42, 3.1459);`  will compile. The results will be comical.

Comment: all the more reason to use a variadic template instead, then the type of the parameters can be locked down so a compiler error occurs if incompatible values are passed in

Answer (score 3):

In C++11 and later, you can use a [variadic template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack):

```cpp
int sum(int value) {
    return value;
}

template<typename... Targs>
int sum(int value, Targs... Fargs) {
    return value + sum(Fargs...);
}

sum(2,5);
sum(3,5,10);
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/cZKAmX)

In C++17 and later, you can use a fold expression to remove the recursion:

```cpp
template<typename... Targs>
int sum(Targs... Fargs) {
    return (Fargs + ...);
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/xJ0GDk)

Alternatively, in C++11 and later, you can use `std::initializer_list`:

```cpp
#include <initializer_list>

int sum(std::initializer_list<int> values) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int value : values) {
        result += value;
    }
    return result;
}

sum({2,5});
sum({3,5,10});
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/T5j3dN)

And then use [`std::accumulate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) to remove the manual loop:

```cpp
#include <initializer_list>
#include <numeric>

int sum(std::initializer_list<int> values) {
    return std::accumulate(values.begin(), values.end(), 0);
}
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/eLHsNU)

If, for some reason, you are not using a C++11 compiler, then you can use an array instead:

```cpp
template<size_t N>
int sum(int (&values)[N]) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        result += values[i];
    }
    return result;
}

int values[] = {2,5};
sum(values);

int values2[] = {3,5,10};
sum(values2);
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/b8qvAg)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a vector or set of numbers and pass that object to the function. Then do the operation and return your sum.

Answer (score -1):

sum(int n_1 = 0, int n_2 = 0, int n_3 = 0)
you can call one, two or three parameters

Comment: And if you need more than 3 numbers? This approach falls apart pretty quick

Comment: This solution applies for more type parameters and with 1-5 numbers parameters, if the same type and more than 5 numbers, you can use an array instead.